# How to use methods on schema in mongoose + express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm getting the following error when I try to run user.comparePassword from exports.index.post (see below) -- I pasted all code to help narrow down the problem. The UserSchema.pre('save') method works fine, but not the one in ./routes/account.js (I'm using mongoose 3)

Here is the error I get.

```
Caught exception: [TypeError: Object { username: 'test4',
  email: 'test4@test.com',
  password: '$2a$10$Ix5vCuVYGIU7AmXglmfIxOyYnF6CiPJfw9HLSAGcRDxMJEttud/F6',
  _id: 505fee7ce28f10711e000002,
  __v: 0 } has no method 'comparePassword']





## ./app.js

app.post('/account', routes.account.index.post);


## ./models/user.js

var mongoose = require('mongoose')
    , bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
  , Schema = mongoose.Schema
  , db = mongoose.createConnection('localhost', 'mydb');

var UserSchema = new Schema({
        username    : { type: String, required: true, index: { unique: true }, trim: true }
    , email       : { type: String, required: true, index: { unique: true }, trim: true, lowercase: true }
    , password    : { type: String, required: true, trim: true }
});

UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    var user = this;

    // only hash the password if it has been modified (or is new)
    if (!user.isModified('password')) return next();

    // generate a salt
    bcrypt.genSalt(function(err, salt) {
        if (err) return next(err);

        // hash the password along with our new salt
        bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
            if (err) return next(err);

            // override the cleartext password with the hashed one
            user.password = hash;
            next();
        });
    });
});

//compare supplied password
UserSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, cb) {
    bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.password, function(err, isMatch) {
        if (err) return cb(err);
        cb(null, isMatch);
    });
};

module.exports = db.model('User', UserSchema);


##./routes/account.js



/*
 * GET account home page.
 */

exports.index = {};
exports.index.get = function(req, res){
    var d = { title: 'Edit account' };
  res.render('account', { d: d } );
};

exports.index.post = function(req, res){
    req.assert('email', 'Enter email').notEmpty().isEmail();
  req.assert('password', 'Enter password').notEmpty().isAlphanumeric().len(5,20);

    //user must confirm password
    if ( req.body.password_new ) {
        req.assert('password_new', 'Enter password').notEmpty().isAlphanumeric().len(5,20);
        req.assert('password_new_confirm', 'Passwords must match').equals(req.body.password);
    }

    res.locals.err = req.validationErrors(true);

    if ( res.locals.err ) {
        var d = { title: 'Edit account' };
        res.render('account', { d: d } );
        return;
    }

    var User = require('../models/user')
    , mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , db = mongoose.createConnection('localhost', 'mydb');

    var user = db.model('User', User.UserSchema);
    user.find({username: req.session.user.username }, function(err, user){
        if ( err ) return next(err);

/*********** THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS **************/

        user.comparePassword(req.body.password, function(err, isMatch) {
            console.log("isMatch", isMatch);
            if (err) next(err);

            if (!isMatch) {
                req.flash('error', 'Woops, looks like you mistyped your password.');
                req.session.user = user;
                res.locals.user = user;
                res.redirect('/account');
                return;
            }

            //user is authenticated
            //session length
            console.log(req.body);
        });

    });


};
```

Comment: It looks like methods aren't available from .find() only from .findOne().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`user.find` queries for 0 or more docs, so the second parameter to its callback is an array of docs, not a single doc.  `user.findOne` queries for 0 or 1 docs, so the second parameter to its callback is either null or that single doc.  So you're trying to call your schema's method on a JavaScript `Array` which of course won't work.  Change that `find` call to a `findOne` and it should work.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to get the user object from inside the user.comparePassword() call?

Comment: @chovy In an instance method like `comparePassword`, `this` is the user doc it was called on.

Comment: Inside the definition, `this` is a user object, but when I call it in async behaviour, `this` gives me the schema, not the user object inside the callback. `user.comparePassword(req.body.password, function(err, isMatch) {  //can't get user here });`

Comment: @chovy You've got `user` right there since you just used it to call `comparePassword`.  That's directly accessible to the callback.

Comment: ok, i don't know why that failed me before, it works as you say.